# Error: javax.servlet.http.HttpSession Cannot Be Resolved in com.hazelcast.web.HazelcastHttpSession

Tags: spring-boot, hazelcast, jakarta-migration

Recently i started migrating from java8 to Java 17 and SpringBoot-2.7.2 to Springboot-3.1.5 .In my project i am using Hazelcast as well and i moved to latest release of Hazelcast-all version  [5.0-BETA-1][1]

but this is creating a issue in the following java code

```
    import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpSession;
    import com.hazelcast.web.HazelcastHttpSession;
    
     
            HttpSession oldSession = request.getSession();
            oldSession.invalidate();
            //creating new session
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    
            if (session instanceof HazelcastHttpSession) {
                sessionService.setSessions(session.getId(), new Session(session.getId(), new Date(), username));
            }
```

While in eclipse class showing error at top line of class

> - The type javax.servlet.http.HttpSession cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required type
>   com.hazelcast.web.HazelcastHttpSession
> - The type javax.servlet.http.HttpSession cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required type com.hazelcast.web.WebFilter

We cant use Hazelcast-all latest version with Springboot ? Look like Hazelcast-all still using `javax.*` in place of `jakarta.*`
[1]: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.hazelcast/hazelcast-all/5.0-BETA-1

Comment: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/23515 Btw, 5.0-BETA-1 definitely isn't the latest release .. The date on your link even says Jul 13, 2021.

Comment: @BalusC Thanks for your update ...Latest release `4.2.8` also i tested but its also using `javax.*` .

Comment: Link in my comment says it's fixed for upcoming 5.4 release.

Comment: Anything else here can be done ,do we have to remove `hazelcast-all` from our project as no release date for `5.4.0`

Comment: Another alternative would be using spring session abstraction with spring-session-hazelcast as backend. This will make life easier for you. Spring session version will be compatible with your spring server version

Comment: @OrçunÇolak Can you add Example?

Comment: I'd suggest to wait for hazelcast official release for jakartaee9 support. If you can't, maybe give a try to eclipse transformer tool. See this [article](https://blog.payara.fish/how-to-use-the-eclipse-transformer-project-to-convert-a-3rd-party-library)